# JPA Repository query multiple tables

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have three tables

Users

```
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private InfoData info;

private String name;
```

InfoData

```
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="info")
private Set<Users> user=new HashSet<Users>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="infoD")
private Set<Results> result=new HashSet<Results>();
```

Results

```
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private InfoData infoD;

private String otherData'
```

`Users` has a foreign key reference to `InfoData`, results also has a foreign key reference to `InfoData`

What I want to do is:
Given a name field in `Users` and the otherData in `Results`, get all other fields from `Results`
So, with the name of User get the infoData Id. And then find this id in the Results table where otherData==to the parameter , from there to pull out information.
How do I do that using JPA repository ?
Do I do it in the infoData Repository,given that I have a bidirectional relationship ?
Or in the Users Repository ?

Or maybe in the InfoData Repository, findBy name of the Users AND otherInfo of Results ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `InfoData` a join table for many-to-many relation between User and Results? (looks like it)

Comment: InfoData is one to many with Users and one to many with Results.
But I think yes. Cuz tables were ready given to me, and this is the relationships reverse engineering provided me with. I guess it doesn't detect many to many relationships